# How can we add annotations, drawings and images in pdf file using javascript

Tags: javascript, pdf, annotations

**Without using libraries** how can we add annotations(edit text, highlighting, underline etc) and drawing circles rectangles and adding images to pdf file with the use of javascript.

> One more thing how this javascript will work on cross platforms(Web +
> Android + IoS). I need a simple abstract for this to understand how JS
> will manipulate PDF file.

`Edit*`
Any open source library/SDK etc also acceptable that can perform on android and iOS

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to edit PDFs in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2803331/how-to-edit-pdfs-in-javascript)

Comment: @MD.RAKIBHASAN your mentioned link is about accessing form field values on server rather manipulating PDF file.

Comment: When you say "drawings and images" are those also Annotations? Or you mean, in addition to adding annotations, you want to edit the PDF page contents themselves to add "drawings and images"?

Comment: Check this out. https://annotationeer.netlify.app/. It is an independent layer that runs on top of the PDF.JS Viewer.